# How to show Current page particular div data on next page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

An example, I have a page A.php and wants to copy some div data and get same data on B.php in WordPress. I'm working on custom plugin development. I also tried session but getting the error. Anyone here to guide me what's the best approach to solve this kind of problems.

**PAGE A.PHP**

Main Page content or you can say any paragraph

Now I want to Get same div content on PAGE **B.PHP**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the DRY principle - Don't Repeat Youself.
I don't see your code but in general if you want paste the SAME code in two places - extract this code to file (or function or class) and include it in both pages.

Comment: Thanks For at least giving some tricks. Otherwise here people only give the negative rating and leave the topic.